# PWA Android and IOS Cache

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-safari, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

We are experiencing a pwa application with services worker and everything that surrounds this theme.

I have questions about cache. Information is currently cached and accessed when offline. This works well when we talk about Android. In IOS it seems that the cache is not shared when we add the application to the home screen (installed). It seems that IOS keeps a cache for the application accessed in Safari and the installed one (I'm talking about the same application). In android it seems that the same cache is shared for the version installed and accessed in chrome.

In IOS after adding the home screen I am forced to log in online to generate the installed application cache.

About IOS would you like to know if you have already gone through this? And what would be the best way to persist this data so that the same cache is shared in the application accessed in Safari and the installed version.

Answer (score 1):

In the service worker you mention the name of the cache, until and unless you change it there or update it e.g;
const staticCacheName = **'pages-cache-v3'**; it will remain same and will be shared among versions. This may be true for the Android am not sure about IOS. Please update me if you have already found a better answer. Cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

If this is still relevant, then I think that you should look at my answer in this question, because you are faced with the same problem.
[PWAs on iOS 12 no longer shares Service Worker cache with Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053580/pwas-on-ios-12-no-longer-shares-service-worker-cache-with-safari/57297282#57297282)