# PWAs on iOS 12 no longer shares Service Worker cache with Safari?

Tags: ios, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

For the PWA on iOS 11 we solved the external third party login opened in Safari by storing the login details in the service worker web cache.

This no longer works in iOS 12 (in beta as of writing). I think this must be because the PWA now has its own service worker cache that it no longer shares with Safari, but I can't confirm this.

Does anyone know if there is a way to share the service worker cache between safari and the PWA? Note that we already tried IndexedDB, but that is not shared, and of course neither are cookies.

As far as I can figure out this means that a PWA is totally sandboxed from safari and there is no way to get a third party login working. Any solutions?

Comment: Perhaps ask this person on twitter https://twitter.com/jonathandavis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth login is now possible as of iOS 12.2 (March 2019) as links of external sites now open in a PWA in-app browser and return links point back to the PWA. As a result I am now able to deploy PWA apps on iOS with third-party Auth0 login (it was already working on Android and Windows).

Note however that login session is not shared between Safari and PWA like in earlier versions of iOS.

I learned of this from [this article](https://medium.com/@firt/whats-new-on-ios-12-2-for-progressive-web-apps-75c348f8e945) from Maximiliano Firtman.

Comment: Your question implies that, on initial deployment in Safari via a URL, you required the user to login, with login details being stored in the cache (strictly speaking, not an integral part of the service worker). You say that it no longer worked after iOS 12 and assumed that it was because the PWA used a separate cache. That seems to imply that you found that the PWA required the user to login again. Is that what you found?

Comment: Further, your answer says that "This is no longer an issue as of iOS 12.2". So have you now fpund that the initial Safari login (before it's added to the homescreen) means that once it's installed as a PWA and added to the homescreen, no additional login is required? (I ask because that's not our experience under iOS 13.5 - the initial Safari login is not recognised when it's accessed as an installed PWA.)

Comment: I can see I was not entirely clear. Since iOS 12 it is no longer possible to share login between safari and PWA. What was fixed in 12.2 was: "When the external URL redirects or points to a URL within the scope -including POST requests, JavaScript redirects or links-, the PWA closes the browser and loads the content in the standalone window, coming back to the original PWA."

In other words we can now use an invoked third party OAuth login in the PWA app, which did not work in iOS 12.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, Tarostar. You've confirmed that our requirement - to allow our users to login to the app on initial access via the URL and maintain that logged in status on switching to the installed PWA (which Android/Chrome allows) - is not possible under Safari/iOS.

Comment: Hi Tarostar. Are you able to display the "Continue as [name]" Facebook login button when someone uses FB login in the installed version of your PWA? Currently when I hit the Facebook Login button from within my installed PWA (works fine on the browser version) it opens a login form in the Facebook app, regardless I'm already logged into the Facebook app. Forcing users to enter their facebook username and password obviously defeats the purpose of having the Facebook Login feature in an app.

Do you know of a way around this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I asked Jonathan Davis(Web Technologies Evangelist for Apple) on twitter about this question. He says Web apps on iOS (“Save to home screen” apps) do not share data stores with Safari. They work as a standalone app separate from Safari and there is no way to share data between them on device.

As a possible solution that may suit you, I propose an article written by Maciej Caputa. Quoting the author the idea is to create a fake endpoint in service worker, which would save data in the cache on POST request and return cached data on GET request. Link on this article https://www.netguru.com/codestories/how-to-share-session-cookie-or-state-between-pwa-in-standalone-mode-and-safari-on-ios.

Hope this answer was helpful!

Comment: I think OP raises exactly this problem that sharing through cache does not work anymore